# How to create dynamic React Native components

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, react-typescript

I want the button to be dynamically created and used when the click event occurs. The button's creation location should be created 10px to the right of the existing button. Ask for help from great and kind friends.
it is my code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Button } from 'react-native'
const Test = () => { 
    return( 
        <Button title='test' onPress={<Button title='test1'/>}/> 
    ) 
} 
export default Test
```

or

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Button } from 'react-native'
const Test = () => { 
    return( 
        <Button title='test' onPress={ButtonRender}/> 
    ) 
}
const ButtonRender =():any=>{
    return <Button title='test1'/>
}
export default Test
```

I have a problem. It is not created Button. I need help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a State variable `buttonClicked=false`

```
<button onclick={() => setState({buttonClicked=true})}/>
{state.buttonClicked?<button></button>:null}
```

and update state when button clicked

Please set the style for that created button